# Como validar o preço no Qt?

Tags: c++, regex, validação, qt

Gostaria de saber como devo fazer para validar o preço no Qt, da seguinte forma:

Exemplos aceitos: `10,00` / `100,00` / `1.000,00 = true`

Meu código, (mas ta validando true: `10` / `100`)

```
 bool ok;
 QLocale::setDefault(QLocale(QLocale::Portuguese, QLocale::Brazil));
 QLocale brazil; // Constructs a default QLocale
 brazil.toDouble(ui->price->text(), &ok);
 qDebug() <<  ok;
```

Comment: exemplo aceito: `1.00,00` ?

Comment: @Math: heh, errei. Faltou um zero. Ae Math sabe como validar? ficarei muito grato pela ajuda. :)

Comment: adoraria ajudar, mas na verdade nao sei nem oq eh `qt`... soh mais uma coisa que me deixou em duvida na sua pergunta: `mas ta validando true: 10 / 100 / 1000.00` quer dizer que os q tem virgula ele ta retornando falso e apenas os exemplos sem virgula retornam true?

Comment: Olha, acabei de testar aqui com `brazil.toDouble("1000.00", &ok);`, por exemplo, e funcionou (digo, retornou `false` como esperado).

Comment: Entretanto, para valores como `10` e `100` (sem ponto no lugar da vírgula) creio que a validação vai sempre estar correta, pois são números válidos no locale do Brasil.

Comment: Você deveria explicar melhor sua pergunta, eu tentei ajudar porém, ainda ficou confuso.

Comment: ah, agora entendi, para retornar `true` tem que ter o `.` separando os decimais e o `,` caso a parte inteira passe de 999, isso que voce espera @user628298 ?

Comment: @Math: sim. True=1.000,00  false=1000.00

Comment: parece que QLocale não possui essa funcionalidade de verificação de formato que você quer, melhor buscar outros meios de verificação, por exemplo, regex.

Comment: @user628298 Mas, o seu código JÁ faz isso. Ao menos para os exemplos que você acabou de comentar.

Comment: @Luiz Vieira: Sim volta false. Adicionei errado :)

Comment: Ok, então a sua pergunta realmente não está clara. :) Qual é o problema? Não seria que você NÃO quer que validem valores sem a vírgula? Se for esse o caso, a sugestão do @pepper_chico parece ideal: use uma expressão regular.

Comment: @LuizVieira pra mim parece que ele não quer que passe se não tiver virgula. Isso parece claro, e isso QLocale não oferece.

Comment: @pepper_chico Tá parecendo isso mesmo. Mas a pergunta não diz isso claramente.

Comment: @Luiz Vieira: melhor um regex ou adicionar um `código` if(ui->preco->text().length() <= 2){
       qDebug() << text.sprintf("%6.2f", ui->preco->text().toDouble());
     } ? `código`

Comment: O @GuilhermeBernal acabou de postar uma resposta que deve te ajudar. :)

Comment: Obrigado, a todos :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você quer validar precisamente um número no formato de um preço (exatamente duas casas decimais, sem estar no formato exponencial, separador vírgula, separador de milhares ponto), deve usar algo mais preciso que tentar uma conversão para double. Faça com uma regex:

```
QRegularExpression priceRe("^[0-9]{1,3}(\\.[0-9]{3})*,[0-9]{2}$");
QString price = "1.234,53";
if (priceRe.match(price).hasMatch())
    qDebug() << "matched";
```

<sup>[**regexplained**](http://tinyurl.com/ocvt4xo)</sup>

Comment: Blz. Muito obrigado.